# Blender Guru foot roll rig problem

Tags: rigging

I was watching Part 3 of [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging/) on how to rig a foot so that it will roll. Followed the tutorial step-by-step and everything went smooth, but when I rotate the Roll Main bone down on the X axis, the entire foot rotates on the Z axis when it shouldn't. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: maybe in your constraint, you used the incorrect axis?

Comment: No, I am using the correct axis. The foot rig is doing what it is supposed to do when I rotate the Roll Main bone up on the X axis. It's just that....for whatever weird reason it will rotate to the side on the Z axis whenever I rotate that Roll Main bone downward on the X axis.

Comment: could you share your .blend with your model?

Comment: Here's the .blend file - [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2308" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2308/)